# If an Android user disables push notifications for my app in settings, will my app still silently receive them?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

On the "App Info" screen for my application in settings, there's a checkbox that says, "show notifications". If a user unchecks this, will my app still silently receive push notifications, but just be unable to present a notification to the user? Or, will this prevent my app from even receiving the notifications from the server silently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app will still receive push notifications. Your app will not display any notifications in the status bar (you would add those using `NotificationManager)`.

Push notification != notification